# How do I set an on click event for every cell that calls a function which takes id of cell as a parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onclick

Here I created a table and assigned each cell an id. What I want to do is something like this cell1.onclik = MyFunction(this.id);

```
function createTable() {
        var table = document.getElementById("tabela2"); 
        for (let j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            var row = table.insertRow(0);
            for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                cell1.id = "celica" + i + "_" + j; 
            /*doesnt work: cell1.onclik = MyFunction(this.id); */           
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it's `onclick`, not `onclik`. But you should not add a listener for every cell. Instead, you should add only one event listener on the entire table and get the cell id from `e.target.id` (where `e`) is the clickEvent.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use onXXX events. It won't work it there is a content-security-policy on the page.

You just need to listen to the table

```js
    function createTable() {
            var table = document.getElementById("tabela2"); 
//            document.body.appendChild(table);
            for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                var row = table.insertRow(0);
                for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                    cell1.textContent = "1";
                    cell1.id = "celica" + i + "_" + j; 
                }
            }
            table.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              console.log(e.target.id);
              console.log(e.target.tagName);
            });
        }
        
        createTable();
```

```html
<html><body><table id='tabela2'></table></body></html>
```